# I installed pimcore via xampp following the instruction from the website. Now I cannot find the admin page when I try to login

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, httpd.conf, pimcore

Firstly, there is a logo error. The logo is not seen when i enter directory.
Then I am getting a 404 error. Admin page is not found. Kindly explain your answers like you are talking to a total beginner.

I tried some configurations in the httpd.conf file but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest instruction for developer I believe is Demo installation:
https://packagist.org/packages/pimcore/demo

When you played with it a bit you can continue to Skeleton Pimcore Application:

- https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/10.4/Development_Documentation/Getting_Started/Installation.html
- https://github.com/pimcore/skeleton

If you are really beginner, then it is easier to pay: https://bitnami.com/stack/pimcore

If you are total beginner then it would be enough to click in admin panel of official trial version:
https://pimcore.com/en/try
(click any link on the right side of page)